# Archive page of CPT's custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I have a Custom Post Type: "Sponsors"

Sponsors have a Custom Taxonomy: "Sponsor Ranks"
Sponsor Ranks are divided like Platinum Sponsors - Gold Sponsors - Silver Sponsors and so on

I want to make an archive page that will show me all sponsors within their respected rank

Currently I have something that works perfectly fine but I am unsure if this is the right way. I am basically making a new query every time, that doesn't feel right.

```
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'dev_sponsors',
                'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'sponsor_ranks',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array( 'platinum-sponsors' )
                    )
                )
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );     
        ?>
        Platinum Sponsors:<br />
        <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $img = get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'gold'); ?>
            <div class="col-3">
            <?php echo $img; ?><br />
            <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>    
            </div>
         <?php endwhile; 
         wp_reset_postdata();           
         endif; ?>          
    </div>      
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'dev_sponsors',
                'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'sponsor_ranks',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array( 'gold-sponsors' )
                    )
                )
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );     
        ?>
        Gold Sponsors:<br />
        <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $img = get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'gold'); ?>
            <div class="col-3">
            <?php echo $img; ?><br />
            <?php echo $post->post_title; ?>    
            </div>
         <?php endwhile; 
         wp_reset_postdata();           
         endif; ?>          
    </div>
```

Comment: if it works fine then there's no issue, I don't see anything wrong with your queries, but there is no golden path absolute way to do what you're doing, you need to be able to mark an answer as the absolute correct answer and I'm not sure that can be done if you're just looking for reassurance. Also, there is no escaping in your code, you should use escaping functions for security reasons, e.g. `echo esc_html( $post->post_title )`, or better yet `the_title();`, plugins can't filter titles etc if you echo the raw title

Comment: ok thanks, will do!